# Removing the control from another form

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, tabcontrol

Currently I have 2 Forms. `Form1` has some tab controls. I would like to close the tabs from `Form2`.
Form1 is MDI form. Form2 is child form. Form2 is located in tab page in Form1. I just wanna put the close button into the Form2 to close the tab pages in Form1.

```
Form2:

private void btnClose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form1 frm = new Form1();
    frm.tabControl1.TabPages.Remove(frm.tabPage1); 
}
```

This code gives no error but doesn't working in vs2010. Also tried with `RemoveAt`, `RemoveByKey`. The result is the same.

NOTE : I solved the problem to adding the button programmatically from Form1 to Form2.

```
Form1;

Button btn = new Button();
btn.Text = "X";
btn.Width = 23;
btn.Height = 23;
btn.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
btn.Location = new Point(2, 3);
Form2 frm = new Form2();
frm.Controls.Add(btn);
```

Comment: Did my answer work for you? If so, would you mind giving me best answer and confirm that your issue is resolved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class Form1 : Form
{
    //Delegate stuff for performing on UI thread.
    private delegate void TabPageDelegate(TabPage tab);
    private void RemoveTabOnUi(TabPage tab)
    {
        tabControl1.TabPages.RemoveAt(tab);
    }
    //internal method that will be accessible to other members of this namespace.
    internal void RemoveTab(TabPage tab)
    {
        //Do this action on UI delegate.
        this.Invoke(new TabPageDelegate(RemoveTabOnUi), tab);
    }

    //... Form1 Stuff
}
public class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2()
    {
       //Add event to the closing event handler
       this.Closing += OnClosing;
    }
    private void OnClosing(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       //Check to make sure that MdiParent and Parent are correct
       if(null != this.MdiParent && this.MdiParent is Form1 && 
              null != this.Parent && this.Parent is TabPage)
       {
           //Calls the Form1().RemoveTab() internal method 
           ((Form1)this.MdiParent).RemoveTab((TabPage)this.Parent);
       }
    }

    //... Form2 Stuff
}
```

Comment: i shouldn't call frm.Show(); cuz my forms are MDI Form. Form1 is MDI form. Form2 is child form. Form2 is located in tab page. I just wanna put the close button into the Form2 to close the tab pages in Form1.

Comment: It's the same process. But I'll modify.

Comment: @user2071218 I modified it for your needs, but you should be more clear when you are asking these questions. Keep in mind, the reason it didn't work initially is because the fields you were trying to modify were likely private. Not only that, you should never try to modify UI elements on anything other than that UI elements UI thread. (Hints why we used delegates)

Comment: thank you for your codes but it still doesnt work. Gives no error.

Comment: problem is in the OnClosing. Progress doesnt pass the if statement. when i remove the if block and directly execute the code in OnClosing gives null referrence exception error.

Comment: That means either MdiParent or Parent is null or not the correct value. Can you step through them and see what the values of each of them are?